# Android-Html: Is there any way to implement spoilers?

Tags: android, html, xml

sorry for my bad English.
I'm parsing an XML feed and want to know, is there any way to replace
`<blockquote>...</ blockquote>` text to Spoiler? (Collapsible block, e.g. "read more")

Answer (score 1):

You can write this simply with jQuery, but it can be reduced to a markup issue if you were to use jQuery Mobile's [collapsible](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/content/content-collapsible.html) or a Bootstrap [collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse).

**EDIT**:  Actually, if you are never going to run this in a legacy browser, you may be able to simplify a lot with CSS3.  See this example: http://www.cssportal.com/css3-preview/showing-and-hiding-content-with-pure-css3.php#sec1

Comment: This means I need some extra libs?

Comment: While an extra lib isn't required, it makes it a lot easier.